# In Scala what is difference Await, Thread.sleep and for comprehensions?

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, redis

I use Redis with Scala. Redis task is a `future` so I have to study future(Thread).

I found so many ways to wait for a `future` to stop. I don't know what the difference is. What is difference between a `Await`, `Thread.sleep` and `for` comprehensions?

```
  val redisResult1 = redis.set(objectId, value)
  Await.ready(redisResult1, Duration.Inf)

  val redisResult2 = redis.set(objectId, value)
  for {
    _ <- redisResult2
  } yield {
    "end"
  }

  val redisResult3 = redis.set(objectId, value)
  while(redisResult3.isCompleted) Thread.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Ideally, you'd avoid the wait (push it out as far as possible) and chain futures (as in that `for` comprehension).

Comment: if you want to poll in a while loop, it should be `while(!isCompleted)`. But better to use `Await.ready`, which was made for this exact purpose.

Comment: There's two seemingly good answers below hwan, were they any good?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so let's start from the seconds example.
Consider the following code snippet:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Test2{
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
    val f = Future{Thread.sleep(5000); "i'm done"}
    val r = for{
      _ <- f
    } yield "completed"
    println(r)
  }
}
```

Guess what it will print? It prints

```
Future(<not completed>)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So in fact here you are not waiting for the future to complete, you merely map the result of the first future and return it as the other future which will complete after the first one is completed. As you see the program does not wait till the resulting future is completed and just gracefully exits. The `for` comprehension on futures is a sugar syntax for mapping and flatmapping them.

The `Await.result` and `Await.ready` really wait for the future to complete(or timeout to pass). But they make it in a blocking way, so your thread where you you use these methods will be blocked. This is not always very bad and sometimes might be helpful. E.g. in small test programs or REPL session where you want to finally out the result of your future computations to the console, or for example in tests where you anyway need to wait for the result and test has nothing to do while waiting.

Another way to see you result in such small programs is to use `scala.io.StdIn.readLine()` so the main thread will hang around and not exit. Consider the following which illustrates this and also provides you with one more additional way to wait for the future completion:

```
object Test2{
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
    val f = Future{Thread.sleep(5000); "i'm done"}
    f foreach (println(_))

    scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
  }

}
```

Run it and you will see that program does not exit, prints the result of the future and exits then only after you press the ENTER key.

`foreach` applied to the future is a shortcut to adding the `onComplete` listener. Quite handy one.

Regarding the `while` loop continuously checking if the future is completed - I think it is probably the worst way to wait since it will keep the main thread busy and waste more idle CPU power than relying on efficiently implemented `Await.result`. Blocking as other things can as well be efficient and inefficient.

To make a sense of all this stuff with futures you need to realize clearly that actual execution of the future happens not in the same thread where you initiated it. In all our examples we just defined the future in the main thread but then it got executed in one of the thread in the imported `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` execution contexts.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic approach is to not block for the result. Instead you should chain Futures using map/for comprehensions and things like that.

A for comprehension is just syntactic sugar for flatMaps, maps, and withFilters depending on how you use it.

Not only is this as non-blocking as possible, but it allows you to code the "happy path" and not handle failures until as late as possible.

Many frameworks like Play allow you to never block for the Future to finish and allow you to return Futures to the caller and the Framework handles it for you.

If you do have to handle unwrapping the Future, you probably want to be using `onComplete`

Check out [The Neophytes Guide to Scala](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html) for a pretty good tutorial on learning this stuff.